# In what ways does StackOverflow deal with multi-accounting?

Tags: discussion, multiple-accounts

I often have issues policing the problems that having and benefiting from multiple accounts gives on social sites (mainly my webgame http://ninjawars.net).

It certainly seems like multi-accounting would be a problem for stack overflow, how does SO solve/lessen that kind of problem?

Comment: I think that reworking this question a bit would make it SO material.

Comment: Yeah, I guess.  Wasn't sure that it would be acceptable on SO/or how to rework it in that direction, per se.  Maybe there are related questions on SO itself that I can learn from.  Mainly I was just thinking that SO itself might have some slick systems that I could learn from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically we use statistics. There are certain behaviors that are statistically normal, and those that are not.

Accounts and behavior patterns which are statistical outliers get flagged, or automatically reverted.

Comment: @Jeff But.. is it allowed ?  :")

Comment: I see you are trying to use statistics to find multiple accounts. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.